# how to config java APM properties to send application log to APM server / fleet server?

Tags: spring, kibana, elastic-apm

i have different log appender configuration, shown below :

`<appender name="JSON-FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">`

`<appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">`

`<appender name="CONSOLE-OUT-FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">`

and run java agent as :

```
nohup java -javaagent:../elastic-apm-agent-1.35.0.jar -Delastic.apm.log_ecs_formatter_allow_list:ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender -Delastic.apm.service_name=book-service -Delastic.apm.server_urls=http://10.0.114.37:8200 -Delastic.apm.secret_token= -Delastic.apm.environment=development -Delastic.apm.application_packages=com.myapp.book -jar book-service.jar &
tail -f nohup.out
```

my APM agent running well including transaction, metric, Errors, except the log sender.
I got message : There are no log messages to display.Try adjusting your filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the log data is not send by the APM, but I have to configure a log sender, in this case I use `filebeat`. And it works great, every transaction has log corelatively. It is possible because the APM injects `trace.id` and `transaction.id`, my `logback.xml` config looklike this:

```
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>../log/app.log</file>
    <encoder class="co.elastic.logging.logback.EcsEncoder">
        <serviceName>app-service</serviceName>
        <serviceVersion>1.0</serviceVersion>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```